# Invalidate Security Scoped Bookmarks

Tags: macos, security, bookmarks, scoped

Is there a way to invalidate a Security Scoped Bookmark? What I mean is that a bookmark becomes invalid and the user has to re-allow access to the file or folder, even if the app has stored the bookmark. A new bookmark should be issued this way.

Answer (score 0):

The only way a bookmark can become invalid (in that the user needs to grant access to the URL again) is if resolving the bookmark via [`URL(resolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeTo:bookmarkDataIsStale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126805-init) throws, and you don't have access to the original URL where you could create a new bookmark via [`URL.bookmarkData(options:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/2143023-bookmarkdata).

To my knowledge, there is no way for a user to explicitly remove access to a bookmark. A bookmark may become stale (see the `bookmarkDataIsStale` parameter), in which you'll need to use the mentioned `bookmarkData` method to create a new bookmark from the returned URL (note: you don't need to resolve the bookmark again).

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the explanation I expected, but it shows me that there is no way to do what I asked.